# Swapping Bootstrap column order in single row on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an issue with bootstrap columns and can't seem to resolve swapping the order on smaller devices. I don't want these to stack because they stay a single row on desktop, tablet and mobile. However, on Desktop and tablet I want the row in the default order like this:

`Logo Menu Button`

But on phones, I simply want the first two columns swapped, like so:

`Menu Logo Button`

How can I achieve a simple reverse of the columns  while keeping the row?

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-4 col-xs-order-2">
        Logo
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-4 col-xs-order-1">
        Menu
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 hidden-lg col-xs-order-3">
        Button
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update:
screenshot of current result
[image]

Comment: @manjirosano I added a screenshot as well as a bootsrap link in my code (that was my fault for omitting)

Comment: So, the only way I can see you making this work, would be through `media queries` and make some sort of `hidden` div on normal width, but when it gets a phone width, you make it `display: block` with the order that you want. (probably not best solution, but it's the only thing I can think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Bootstrap-4 dropped the `order-xs` class as it is the default class. If you want to apply changes for only `xs`-classes you have to change the roder for all elements and use `order-sm-`-class to correct the order at `sm`-width:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-4 order-2 sm-order-1">
        Logo
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-4 order-1 sm-order-2">
        Menu
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 hidden-lg order-3 sm-order-3">
        Button
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in your example everything is stacked, is there a way to swap them in the same row still?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
        Menu
        </div>
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 order-sm-first">
        Logo
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 hidden-lg">
        Button
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```